# Delete partition directories from HDFS, would it reflect in hive table?

Tags: hive, hive-partitions

Lets say I created a hive table with partition column as year, month and day and if i delete the partition from hdfs, then result get reflected in hive table or not

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the partition"? Delete all directories + files? delete only the sub-directories and put the files in the top directory?

Comment: Delete the all directories + files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update partition metadata in Hive , when partition data is manualy deleted from HDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108251/how-to-update-partition-metadata-in-hive-when-partition-data-is-manualy-delete)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The partition data will be gone.
The metastore will still hold the partition information (metadata) and you can see it using `show partition mytable`.
You can find the partitions need to be dropped using `msck repair mytable`.
You can drop the partitions using `alter table mytable drop partition (...)`

Comment: Yes, but that result will get reflected in hive table or not?

Comment: off-course it will. How can you query a table and see data that does not exist any more?

Comment: Thanks!!
It helps me to understand the partition deletion

Comment: `msck repair` doesn't not reflect manually deleted folders in the metastore, it only adds partitions that are on HDFS but not in the metastore to the metastore.

Comment: @cheseaux - does not drop but does reflect. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44931540/6336479 I have fixed this answer. Thanks

Comment: `This does not cause any issue` I also disagree with your point, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456932/aggregate-queries-fail-in-hive-if-partition-directory-doesnt-exist) for example. I also experimented a lot of issues with manually deleted partition files. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45036445/1852681) to a related question.

Comment: @cheseaux - you might got a point. Different engines, different versions, different bugs.

Comment: Superb !! 
By using msck repair mytable i can able to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Hive table will still show the partitions, you will have to either drop the partitions deleted on HDFS manually (or drop and re-create table) and run MSCK.

**Commands:**

If you intend to alter the table and drop all deleted partitions-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP [IF EXISTS] PARTITION partition_spec[, PARTITION partition_spec, ...]
  [IGNORE PROTECTION] [PURGE];            -- (Note: PURGE available in Hive 1.2.0 and later, IGNORE PROTECTION not available 2.0.0 and later)
```

I would go with drop and re-create table then run MSCK.

To add all existing partitions to table-

```
msck repair table <table_name>
```

Alternatively, you could drop all partitions using `ALTER TABLE` and then run the `MSCK` command.